# Problems installing packages using pip

Tags: python-2.7, download, pip, mechanize

I have been trying to install Mechanize for Python 2.7, and I had trouble installing it directly from a website. Then I tried pip. I believe that I have pip already because ">>>import pip" doesn't result in an error. I looked at several websites about installing things with pip, but they result in an error.

> import pip
>   pip install mechanize

Yields SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have read that the pip may need to be upgraded, but

> python -m pip install -U pip setuptools

also results in an error.

**Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong, or another way to download Mechanize?** 
Any help would be much appreciated. If this already has been answered somewhere else, please post the link.

Comment: `pip install` isn't Python code, it's a shell command.

Comment: You should really read up on what pip is and what it does. It's a package manager that installs Python packages and is for the *shell*, not the Python interpreter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `pip install mechanize` in the terminal directly and not in python console.

Comment: This is going to make me sound really idiotic and incompetent, but is the terminal the black background and white text program that you can type directly into? If so, I have tried it there, but it produced a syntax error. I have also tried running it in the IDLE program with the same effect.

Comment: Terminal or shell is where you type `python` to start the python console. Try running the above command with sudo, that might help.

Comment: What is sudo? Is that a code? I'm sorry, I am very new.

Comment: try `sudo pip install mechanize`